# Efficiently read and parse large one line text files

Tags: python, text-files, readline, large-files, word-wrap

Would like to hear your approaches on how to parse a large txt file with one single line and writing to another file every block of 180 characters in new lines. Avoiding loading all data into memory first if possible.
Thanks

Comment: We would like to hear *your* approaches before.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect application for a generator.https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Also, shouldn't f.read(180) should read 180 chars and not have to read the entire string into memory....

Comment: You already gave the answer. If you don't like to read the whole file at once, read it in blocks of 180 characters.

Comment: if you are doing line by line, then python has built in functionality for this (E.G. `for line in file: #insert code here` )

Comment: @utdemir all my tentative s are basically reading the file with f.readline into another file but not finding the correct way of parsing them effectively. Well at the end i should have started my post with an "how to" question and not searching for approaches.

Comment: @Natecat The question is about reading a file with just one line, so iterating over lines does not help this time.

Answer (score 2):

`readline` reads entire lines.

Since your entire input is one line, it will read the entire input.

As Josh A. commented, use `read(x)` instead in order to read a chunk of `x` characters at a time.